# Keys with null values are getting removed from org.json.JSONObject when we call toString() on org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am using org.json.JSONObject to create a json object and storing following values in it :

```
    val chkStatusJson = JSONObject()
    chkStatusJson.put("code",0)
    chkStatusJson.put("message",null)
```

When I do toString() on the chkStatusJson  following string is generated :

```
{"code":0}
```

This is wrong right. It should be following :

```
{"code":0,"message":null}
```

Problem is I need complete json string even with null values. Is there way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could also try using `JSONObject.NULL` to represent a `null` value.

Here is a pretty old, but hopefully working example.
https://gist.github.com/iperdomo/2867928